# Error inicializar matriz de char error: too many initializers for ‘char [8]’

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un tablero para un juego y para eso quiero utilizar una matriz de char pero al inicializarla me da un error y no encuentro el fallo

```
int main(){
    char tablero[8][8]={
        {"v","i","c","t","o","r","i","a"},
        {"9","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"},
        {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "},
        {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "},
        {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "},
        {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "},
        {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "},
        {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "}
    };
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La verdad no se programar en C++ así que no estoy seguro de que esto resuelva la pregunta, en todo caso he probado cambiando las dobles comillas `"` por comillas simples `'`.

Llegué a ello probando cada vez una porción de código más reducida:

```
int main(){
    char tablero[2]={"v","i"};
}
```

Aún lanzando el mismo problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y probando con:

```
int main(){
    char tablero[2]={'v','i'};
}
```

Ya no me lanza el error de compilación. He comprobado con el código completo de la pregunta e igualmente no lanza error de compilación.

Comment: ese era el problema muchas gracias

Comment: Estás en lo correcto. En C++ los literales funcionan de forma similar a las de C#, comillas dobles para strings y simples para carácteres individuales. Con la pequeña diferencia de que en C++ en realidad representa un `char*`.

Comment: Dato curioso: también puedes inicializar un `char[]` con un literal de `char*` (el de comillas dobles). Así: `char saludo[5] = "Hola"`. Nótese que en este caso el array debe tener un carácter más de tamaño porque el literal añade un carácter nulo al final de la cadena.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de declarar e inicializar la matriz sería sin las comas,

te dejo aqui el ejemplo con tu código:

```
int main(){

const int size = 8;

char tablero[size][size + 1]={
    {"Victoria"},
    {"91234567"},
    {" "},
    {" "},
    {" "},
    {" "},
    {" "},
    {" "}
};}
```

Cabe destacar que tienes que usar [size+1] por que al final de cada string tiene que haber un caracter NULL "\0"